# Search for string inside pdf with pdfgrep and outputs only file name

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, grep, xargs

I'm using pdfgrep to search for a name inside a pdf:

```
pdfgrep -H 'Fatima Alves' RE/*
```

This commands will output the file name and the name:

```
RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923(1).PDF: Fatima Alves   
RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923 (2).PDF: Fatima Alves
```

But i would like to print only the file name, without the `: Fatima Alves`

Cause i would like to use a pipe with xargs to move the matche files:

```
pdfgrep -H 'Fatima Alves' RE/* | xargs -I{} mv -i {} ./destination
```

But in the current situation, the move doesn't work cause is trying to move a file that doesn't exist:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923(1).PDF: Fatima Alves’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923 (2).PDF: Fatima Alves’: No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: -H prints the filenames and the :Fatima Alves in the final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `pdfgrep` output like follows to make it usable in `xargs`:

```
$ echo 'RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923(1).PDF: Fatima Alves' | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching '.*(?=: Fatima Alves$)'
RE/2011-01-RE_60822079000168_23022016_153923(1).PDF
```

So for any given regular expression and `pdfgrep` output, you can do this:

```
regex='Fatima Alves'
pdfgrep -H "$regex" RE/* | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching ".*(?=: $regex\$)"
```

Edit:

I originally thought only the matching part of the line was printed by `pdfgrep`. Since it prints the whole line we have to simply **remove everything including and following the colon separator**:

```
pdfgrep -H "$regex" RE/* | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Comment: PDF are binary, i can't use only grep, i need use pdfgrep :/

Comment: Updated to clarify.

Comment: Hei @l0b0, thanks very MUCH for the answer! I'm with difficult. Checkout the output: http://i.imgur.com/qxYHDP8.png

Comment: We are almost there, this is the output: http://i.imgur.com/moNYxG2.png The "mv: cannot stat" error happens because there is spaces in the name, right? adding -0 to xargs: | xargs -0 will solve (if i'm right), now we have one last problem, the  command is stuck in the first file, like a infinite loop, do u know why?

Comment: @FátimaAlves No, it probably gives the errors because some files have been moved already at some point. The output of `pdfgrep` should be sorted already since most likely files are processed in the same order the `RE/*` glob expands to, so simply passing the output to `uniq` first should fix that: `pdfgrep -H "$regex" RE/* | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching ".*(?=: $regex\$)" | uniq | [...]`. @l0b0, I'd discourage the `sed` solution, as filenames containing colons are allowed in *nix.

Comment: @kos As long as there's no way to know whether a colon character is part of the filename you can't reliably get to a 100% solution for this problem, so I'm going for a 99% solution. And you should `sort -u` in case `pdfgrep` for whatever reason can output lines in a mangled sequence.

Comment: The `grep` solution is 100% safe actually. And actually you can have a 100% safe solution with `sed` as well: `pdfgrep -H "$regex" RE/* | sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/'`.

Comment: @kos, can't we modify this regex to avoid everything until the last :?? I'm trying like javascript (with ? sign): sed 's/\(.*?\):.*/\1/' but isn't working.

Comment: @FátimaAlves I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly. "Avoid everything until the last `:`" as in "discard everything until the last `:`" (i.e. printing only what's after the last `:`)?

Comment: Ops, sorry.. i mean "Match everything until the first :" hahahaha

Comment: In the current situation, the regex is matching everything until the last :, and somethings i need catch docs with some hour, like 22:00:00, this would be a problem.

Comment: @FátimaAlves: When you say "hahahaha", it seems like you're joking around, and that you're not serious about getting an answer to your question.  If people believe that, they'll feel that you're wasting our time, and they might not want to help you any more.

Comment: Thanks for the really good tip, professor.. HAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAH

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to build up the command incrementally. You can get the list of matching filenames using:

```
$ pdfgrep -i "Fatima Alves" *.pdf | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

After running the above command and ensuring it generates the expected output, you can use Bash [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) (`$()`) and [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html) (`!!`) to quickly re-run it and move the files, like so:

```
$ mv $(!!) ./destination
```

Of course, you can re-type the whole command instead, if you prefer:

```
$ mv -i $(pdfgrep -i "Fatima Alves" *.pdf | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u) ./destination
```

Note that this will fail under two circumstances:

1. The pathological case where no files match the pattern will result in a somewhat cryptic error saying: `mv: missing destination file operand after './destination'`
2. Files with spaces in the name will cause problems.

Personally, I haven't bothered figuring out a workaround for these two failure modes because I always run such 'match + action' commands in two stages (so I always know whether there were zero matches, and the action can therefore be skipped) and I scrupulously avoid filenames with spaces in them. But if needed, you could add something like `| sed 's/ /\\ /g` to the end of the command substitution pipeline to escape the spaces.